# Trying unparse json string, but getting Expected start of the object '{', but had 'EOF' instead

Tags: json, kotlin, parsing, serialization

I am trying to parse a json file into a list using kotlin serializable.
Here are my data classes.

```
    @Serializable
data class Book(
    val epub : String,
    val fb2 : String,
    val mobi : String,
    val djvu : String,
    val title : String,
    val author : String,
    val anotation: String,
    val cover_uri : String,
)

@Serializable
data class Books(
    @Serializable (with = BookListSerializer::class)
    val books : List<Book>
)

object  BookListSerializer  :  JsonTransformingSerializer < List < Book >> ( ListSerializer ( Book.serializer ()))
```

Here I am trying to parse a string

```
val books = Json.decodeFromString<Books>(stringJson)
```

Here my Json String

```
[
  {
    "anotation": "Этот город",
    "author": "Чарльз Плэтт",
    "cover_uri": "null",
    "djvu": "null",
    "epub": "/b/301494/epub",
    "fb2": "/b/301494/fb2",
    "mobi": "/b/301494/mobi",
    "title": "New York Times (Пульс Нью-Йорка) (fb2)"
  },
  {
    "anotation": "Способна л",
    "author": "Триш Уайли",
    "cover_uri": "/i/45/390445/cover.jpg",
    "djvu": "null",
    "epub": "/b/390445/epub",
    "fb2": "/b/390445/fb2",
    "mobi": "/b/390445/mobi",
    "title": "Лучший мужчина Нью-Йорка (fb2)"
  }
]
```

And i always getting this error

```
kotlinx.serialization.json.internal.JsonDecodingException: Expected start of the object '{', but had 'EOF' instead
    JSON input: .....2","mobi":"/b/49442/mobi","title":"I love New York (fb2)"}]
```

I would be very glad and grateful for any help

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**tl;dr**

Exchange this

```kotlin
val books = Json.decodeFromString<Books>(stringJson)
```

with this

```kotlin
val books = Json.decodeFromString<List<Book>>(stringJson)
```

---

You're trying to deserialize an JSON array `[ ... ]` but declare an object of type `Books` as target when calling `decodeFromString`, thus something like `{ books: [ ... ] }`.

You either have to wrap your JSON array in the property `books` of an JSON object or change the expected type during deserialization to `List<Book>`.

Thus, besides the above solution, you could also do the following:

```kotlin
val wrappedStringJson = """
    {
      "books": $stringJson
    }
""".trimIndent()
val books = Json.decodeFromString<Books>(wrappedStringJson)
```

Comment: ...
I don't know how I could have missed it, thank you very much. Now its working)

Answer (score 4):

I experienced the same issue during testing on Ktor Server.

```
fun testFun() = testApplication { ....
val response = client.get("/boruto/heroes")
val actual = Json.decodeFromString<ApiResponse>(response.content.toString())
....
}
```

The issue was that I was using this ***content*** instead of ***body***.

`val actual = Json.decodeFromString<T>(response.content.toString())`

I changed it to  this and the test passed

`val actual = Json.decodeFromString<T>(response.body())`

Leaving this here in case someone encounters the same issue.