# Expected start of the array '[', but had 'EOF' instead

Tags: android, json, kotlin, serialization

I'm trying to fetch data from API. My app crashes and it gives me this error:

> kotlinx.serialization.json.internal.JsonDecodingException: Expected start of the array '[', but had 'EOF' instead     JSON input: {         "generated_at": "2022-05-20T10:29:36+00:00",         "summaries": []     }

I searched for a solution and found a website that corrects any errors in a json response, but unfortunately it didn't work.

This is my json response (Not the whole response, just one item):

```
{
"generated_at": "2022-05-20T09:40:26+00:00",
"schedules": [
    {
        "sport_event": {
            "id": "sr:sport_event:27751052",
            "start_time": "2021-08-13T19:00:00+00:00",
            "start_time_confirmed": true,
            "sport_event_context": {
                "sport": {
                    "id": "sr:sport:1",
                    "name": "Soccer"
                },
                "category": {
                    "id": "sr:category:1",
                    "name": "England",
                    "country_code": "ENG"
                },
                "competition": {
                    "id": "sr:competition:17",
                    "name": "Premier League",
                    "gender": "men"
                },
                "season": {
                    "id": "sr:season:83706",
                    "name": "Premier League 21\/22",
                    "start_date": "2021-08-13",
                    "end_date": "2022-05-22",
                    "year": "21\/22",
                    "competition_id": "sr:competition:17"
                },
                "stage": {
                    "order": 1,
                    "type": "league",
                    "phase": "regular season",
                    "start_date": "2021-08-13",
                    "end_date": "2022-05-22",
                    "year": "21\/22"
                },
                "round": {
                    "number": 1
                },
                "groups": [
                    {
                        "id": "sr:league:56620",
                        "name": "Premier League 21\/22"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "coverage": {
                "type": "sport_event",
                "sport_event_properties": {
                    "lineups": true,
                    "extended_player_stats": true,
                    "extended_team_stats": true,
                    "lineups_availability": "pre",
                    "ballspotting": true,
                    "commentary": true,
                    "fun_facts": true,
                    "goal_scorers": true,
                    "scores": "live",
                    "game_clock": true,
                    "deeper_play_by_play": true,
                    "deeper_player_stats": true,
                    "deeper_team_stats": true,
                    "basic_play_by_play": true,
                    "basic_player_stats": true,
                    "basic_team_stats": true
                }
            },
            "competitors": [
                {
                    "id": "sr:competitor:50",
                    "name": "Brentford FC",
                    "country": "England",
                    "country_code": "ENG",
                    "abbreviation": "BRE",
                    "qualifier": "home",
                    "gender": "male"
                },
                {
                    "id": "sr:competitor:42",
                    "name": "Arsenal FC",
                    "country": "England",
                    "country_code": "ENG",
                    "abbreviation": "ARS",
                    "qualifier": "away",
                    "gender": "male"
                }
            ],
            "venue": {
                "id": "sr:venue:53349",
                "name": "Brentford Community Stadium",
                "capacity": 17250,
                "city_name": "London",
                "country_name": "England",
                "map_coordinates": "51.4907295,-0.2891696",
                "country_code": "ENG"
            }
        },
        "sport_event_status": {
            "status": "closed",
            "match_status": "ended",
            "home_score": 2,
            "away_score": 0,
            "winner_id": "sr:competitor:50",
            "period_scores": [
                {
                    "home_score": 1,
                    "away_score": 0,
                    "type": "regular_period",
                    "number": 1
                },
                {
                    "home_score": 1,
                    "away_score": 0,
                    "type": "regular_period",
                    "number": 2
                }
            ]
        }
    }]}
```

This is some of the data classes:

```
    @Serializable
data class Schedules(
    @SerialName("generated_at")
    val generatedAt: String,
    @SerialName("schedules")
    val schedules: List<Schedule>
)



    @Serializable
data class Schedule(
    @SerialName("sport_event")
    val sportEvent: SportEvent,
    @SerialName("sport_event_status")
    val sportEventStatus: SportEventStatus
)



@Serializable
data class SportEvent(
    @SerialName("competitors")
    val competitors: List<Competitor>,
    @SerialName("coverage")
    val coverage: Coverage,
    @SerialName("id")
    val id: String,
    @SerialName("sport_event_context")
    val sportEventContext: SportEventContext,
    @SerialName("start_time")
    val startTime: String,
    @SerialName("start_time_confirmed")
    val startTimeConfirmed: Boolean,
    @SerialName("venue")
    val venue: Venue
)
```

Logcat:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: DefaultDispatcher-worker-1
Process: com.example.a356scoresclone, PID: 19000
kotlinx.serialization.json.internal.JsonDecodingException: Expected start of the array '[', but had 'EOF' instead
JSON input: {
    "generated_at": "2022-05-20T10:47:43+00:00",
    "summaries": []
}
    at kotlinx.serialization.json.internal.JsonExceptionsKt.JsonDecodingException(JsonExceptions.kt:24)
    at kotlinx.serialization.json.internal.JsonExceptionsKt.JsonDecodingException(JsonExceptions.kt:32)
    at kotlinx.serialization.json.internal.JsonLexer.fail(JsonLexer.kt:493)
    at kotlinx.serialization.json.internal.JsonLexer.fail(JsonLexer.kt:215)
    at kotlinx.serialization.json.internal.JsonLexer.unexpectedToken(JsonLexer.kt:198)
    at kotlinx.serialization.json.internal.JsonLexer.consumeNextToken(JsonLexer.kt:188)
    at kotlinx.serialization.json.internal.StreamingJsonDecoder.beginStructure(StreamingJsonDecoder.kt:37)
    at kotlinx.serialization.internal.AbstractCollectionSerializer.merge(CollectionSerializers.kt:29)
    at kotlinx.serialization.internal.AbstractCollectionSerializer.deserialize(CollectionSerializers.kt:43)
    at kotlinx.serialization.json.internal.PolymorphicKt.decodeSerializableValuePolymorphic(Polymorphic.kt:63)
    at kotlinx.serialization.json.internal.StreamingJsonDecoder.decodeSerializableValue(StreamingJsonDecoder.kt:32)
    at kotlinx.serialization.json.Json.decodeFromString(Json.kt:100)
    at com.jakewharton.retrofit2.converter.kotlinx.serialization.Serializer$FromString.fromResponseBody(Serializer.kt:30)
    at com.jakewharton.retrofit2.converter.kotlinx.serialization.DeserializationStrategyConverter.convert(DeserializationStrategyConverter.kt:11)
    at com.jakewharton.retrofit2.converter.kotlinx.serialization.DeserializationStrategyConverter.convert(DeserializationStrategyConverter.kt:7)
    at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.parseResponse(OkHttpCall.java:243)
    at retrofit2.OkHttpCall$1.onResponse(OkHttpCall.java:153)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall$AsyncCall.run(RealCall.kt:520)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
    Suppressed: kotlinx.coroutines.DiagnosticCoroutineContextException: [StandaloneCoroutine{Cancelling}@34fb196, Dispatchers.IO]
```

Edit:
I've just realized that I have the wrong endpoint. So instead of writing "schedules.json" I have "summaries.json". But still I have a similar error:

```
    kotlinx.serialization.json.internal.JsonDecodingException: Expected start of the array '[', but had 'EOF' instead
JSON input: .....match_status": "not_started"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Probably this may help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/70101955/10248593

Answer (score 4):

I know this doesn't directly answer the question mentioned above but I am posting this here as I had a similar issue during testing on Ktor Server.

This was the error I got.

> kotlinx.serialization.json.internal.JsonDecodingException: Expected
> start of the object '{', but had 'EOF' instead

*EOF* in JSON just means End of File

This was my code:

```
fun testFun() = testApplication { ....
val response = client.get("/boruto/heroes")
val actual = Json.decodeFromString<ApiResponse>(response.content.toString())
....
}
```

I realized the problem occurred as I was using  ***reponse.content*** instead of ***response.body***.

`val actual = Json.decodeFromString<T>(response.content.toString())`

I changed it to this and the test eventually passed

`val actual = Json.decodeFromString<T>(response.body())`

I'm leaving this here in case someone encounters the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

you have printed your JSON in log, which is passed to parser

```
{
    "generated_at": "2022-05-20T10:47:43+00:00",
    "summaries": []
}
```

your parser was expecting `"schedules"` array (even empty), but didn't found such key (no array, no object, no value)

so in fact your response doesn't look like posted JSON (which is valid)

Comment: What should I do to solve my problem?

Comment: send from server-side proper JSON with structure you are expecting... (so with `schedules` array, not empty `summaries`)

Comment: I'm copying the json response exactly what I receive from the server

Comment: As you can see from my question above. My response includes two variables: Expected at and schedules array, there is no summaries. I don't know where it came from.

Comment: you have printed your JSON in exception log. no, you are not getting structure posted in question, you are getting only short one, which is logged with stacktrace and present in my answer in readable format. just try to log by yourself obtained JSON before parsing and you will ensure that

Comment: I had a mistake with the endpoint. I was calling for summaries instead of calling for schedules. But Still I have a similar error.

Comment: so edit your question and post new stacktrace